# Can we use the same API that Google Latitude APP is using for discovering location?

Tags: cellid

I have a device that sends me 
Mobile Country Code (MCC)
Mobile Network Code  (MNC)
Location area code (LAC)
and
Cell ID
of each closest mobile tower in my region. Google Latitude APP is using this info to detect my location. I would like to make my own app that could use same technique, but I can't find any Google API description.

There is a possibility to use [OpenCellID](http://www.opencellid.org/) for my purpose, but there are no CellIDs available for country where I live.

There are some posts where are outdated links to API which I need https://developers.google.com/gears/ and http://www.google.com/glm/mmap but seems like none of them work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using google Maps api:

https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=es

They there's an option `&sensor=true` to detect if you are trying to get the latitude and longitude from a device.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. Device is GPS Tracker, it sends all location parameters through GPRS to my server. As I understand, sensor parameter detects location from browser.

Comment: I think the sensor parameter uses the smartphone's GPS, to use browser for location you must use the HTML5 geolocation API, wich is not needed actually for the sensor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP script that takes parameters `mcc`, `mnc`, `lac` and `cid` and returns `latitude:longitude` if a result is available, `NOT_FOUND` if no result is found. This makes use of the same Google API you've mentioned.

```
<?php


$data = 
"\x00\x0e". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00". 
"\x1b". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x03".
"\x00\x00".
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00". 
"\xff\xff\xff\xff". 
"\x00\x00\x00\x00"  
;
  $mcc = substr("00000000".dechex($_REQUEST["mcc"]),-8);
  $mnc = substr("00000000".dechex($_REQUEST["mnc"]),-8);
  $lac = substr("00000000".dechex($_REQUEST["lac"]),-8);
  $cid = substr("00000000".dechex($_REQUEST["cid"]),-8);


$init_pos = strlen($data);
$data[$init_pos - 38]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 37]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 36]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 35]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,6,2));
$data[$init_pos - 34]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 33]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 32]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 31]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,6,2));
$data[$init_pos - 24]= pack("H*",substr($cid,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 23]= pack("H*",substr($cid,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 22]= pack("H*",substr($cid,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 21]= pack("H*",substr($cid,6,2));
$data[$init_pos - 20]= pack("H*",substr($lac,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 19]= pack("H*",substr($lac,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 18]= pack("H*",substr($lac,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 17]= pack("H*",substr($lac,6,2));
$data[$init_pos - 16]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 15]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 14]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 13]= pack("H*",substr($mnc,6,2));
$data[$init_pos - 12]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,0,2));
$data[$init_pos - 11]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,2,2));
$data[$init_pos - 10]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,4,2));
$data[$init_pos - 9]= pack("H*",substr($mcc,6,2));

if ((hexdec($cid) > 0xffff) && ($mcc != "00000000") && ($mnc != "00000000")) {
  $data[$init_pos - 27] = chr(5);
} else {
  $data[$init_pos - 24]= chr(0);
  $data[$init_pos - 23]= chr(0);
}

$context = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/binary\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
            )
        );

$xcontext = stream_context_create($context);
$str=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/glm/mmap",FALSE,$xcontext);
if (strlen($str) > 10) {
  $lat_tmp = unpack("l",$str[10].$str[9].$str[8].$str[7]);
  $lon_tmp = unpack("l",$str[14].$str[13].$str[12].$str[11]);
  $lon = $lon_tmp[1]/1000000;
  $lat = $lat_tmp[1]/1000000;
  echo $lat.":".$lon;


  }
   else{echo "NOT_FOUND";}

?>
```

Save the code as a php file (I've used locate.php in the example below), upload it to your web host and you can make a query as :
`http://yourwebhost.com/locate.php?mcc=XXX&mnc=XXX&lac=XXXXX&cid=XXXXXXXX`
You can then parse the response obtained to get latitude and longitude information.